# React Navigation Typescript error when using NativeStackScreenProps

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a Stack Navigator nested inside a Tab Navigator. Following this documentation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens) I am trying to use NativeStackScreenProps in order to access the navigation prop. However inside my Stack Navigator

```
<HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={TabHomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
```

gives the following error:

```
Type '({ navigation }: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<HomeStackParamList, "Home"> | undefined'.
  Type '({ navigation }: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': navigation, routets(2322)
types.d.ts(318, 5): The expected type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteConfig<HomeStackParamList, "Home", StackNavigationState<ParamListBase>, NativeStackNavigationOptions, NativeStackNavigationEventMap>'
```

My code is:

**App.tsx**

```
export type RootTabParamList = {
  HomeStack: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamList>;
  Likes: undefined;
  Chats: undefined;
  Settings: undefined;
};
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

export type HomeStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  SendLike: undefined;
};
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator<HomeStackParamList>();
const HomeScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={TabHomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="SendLike" component={StackSendLikeScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeScreenStack} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {if (focused === true) {return (<HomeTabLogoColored/>)} return(<HomeTabLogo/>)}}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Likes" component={TabLikesScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {if (focused === true) {return(<LikesTabLogoColored/>)} return(<LikesTabLogo/>)}}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Chats" component={TabChatsScreen} options={{tabBarBadge: 23, tabBarBadgeStyle: {backgroundColor: COLORS.primaryTwo}, tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {if (focused === true) {return(<ChatsTabLogoColored/>)} return(<ChatsTabLogo/>)}}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={TabSettingsScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {if (focused === true) {return(<SettingsTabLogoColored/>)} return(<SettingsTabLogo/>)}}}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**TabHomeScreen.tsx**

```
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootTabParamList, 'HomeStack'>;

export function TabHomeScreen({navigation}: Props) {
    return (
      <MenuProvider>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View>
            <RoundButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeStack', {screen: "SendLike"})}/>
          </View>
...
```

I am new to typescript and I really don't know what I am doing wrong.
I am also following this repo, and I can't see the difference: https://github.com/dasaco/react-native-navigation-tutorial/blob/master/AppTabNavigator.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code and the documentation, in the file `TabHomeScreen.tsx`, you've `type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootTabParamList, 'HomeStack'>;` which effectively makes `type Props = RootTabParamList["HomeStack"] & {navigation: // typeof navigation, routets: // typeof routets}`, Since `TabHomeScreen` is a screen and not a nested navigator, I think what you're looking for is `type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList, 'Home'>;` in the `TabHomeScreen.tsx` file.